# how to display data stored in JSON file by entering an value in input field and fetching data corresponding to that value or id using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

https://plnkr.co/edit/iZqalOkrpSnjIzwvGchO?p=preview

How to get the data corresponding to each serial number entered in search box
What's missing in the code

```
{
    "SerialNumbers": {
        "451651": [{
            "Owner": "Mr Happy"
        }],
        "5464565": [{
            "Owner": "Mr Red"
        }],
        "45165": [{
            "Owner": "Mr Sad"
        }],
        "4692": [{
            "Owner": "Mr Green"
        }],
        "541": [{
            "Owner": "Mr Blue"
        }],
        "D4554160N": [{
            "Owner": "Mr Loud"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the plunker you shared,

1. There is no controller named `MyController`
2. You are referring to `MyController` instead of `MainCtrl`
3. `angular.module('myApp', [])` - myApp module was created twice. if you want to extend the modue use `angular.module('myApp')` - which returns the existing module.
4. In your `findValue` method, you are not resetting the `result` array. I modified your `findValue` code to following,

   `$scope.findValue = function(enteredValue) {
          $scope.results = Object.keys($scope.data.SerialNumbers)
              .filter(function(key) {
                 return key === enteredValue;
              }).map(function(key) {
                 return {
                   serial: key,
                   owner: $scope.data.SerialNumbers[key][0].Owner
                 };
              });
   };`

**Working plunker:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/N82OhOwKYcW6JEk6sjkI?p=preview